# Cut a portion of a cell value then edit and paste the results into a separate cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I have a cell value that contains an address. I'd like to cut a portion of that data then edit and paste the results into a separate cell. I don't know the specific language to clearly outline my question so any help would be appreciated. I created annotated images to help.

1. Original .CSV data I imported into Google Sheets
   [image: screenshot1]
2. The data from that import that I would like to extract within the cell.
   [image: screenshot2]
3. Data output once I run the Macros script. Original cell data is copy, edited, and pasted into next column.
   [image: screenshot3]

I have thousands of data entries like this so ideally this script would:

1. Cut all data starting at 'County:' from **Premise Address** column.
2. Paste that data into the **County** column while removing 'County:'

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the **Split Text to Column** function in sheets. Then **Find and Replacing** the remaining unnecessary text. It's not pretty but it worked.

Gonna dig into REGEXEXTRACT formulae tonight for some fun reading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple different ways to do this but the simplest would be to use the `REGEXEXTRACT` formulae; if the data structure is exactly the same across all samples, you could use the following one in the **County** column -

```
=IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"County: (.*)"))
```

Assuming that the first **Premise Address** is in **A2** cell.

Comment: @Get_Rude - did this help in any way though?